# How to obtain the analytic representation of the given infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This series is given in Griffiths Introduction to Electrodynamics chapter 3 in an example explaining seperation of variables.

[image]

[image]

I don't have any idea how to get the analytic representation of the series. How to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you know about the complex constructions of the trigonometric functions.

Then remember that
$$
\sum_{n=1,3,5,...}\frac{u^n}n=\frac12(\ln(1+u)-\ln(1-u))=\frac12\ln\frac{1+u}{1-u}
$$
for $|u|<1$. Note that for $x>0$ we have that $|e^{-x\pm y}|=e^{-x}<1$.

Next apply that $$\sin(nu)=\frac1{2i}(e^{inu}-e^{-inu})$$ so that, and use that $\frac{u+iv}{u-iv}$ is a point on the unit circle with angle $2\arg(u+iv)=2\tan^{-1}\frac vu$.

Then combined, and leaving out factors that are not important for this calculation, we get
$\DeclareMathOperator\Ln{Ln}$
\begin{align}
4\sum_{n=1,3,5,...}e^{-nx}\sin(ny)
&=\frac2i\sum_{n=1,3,5,...}e^{n(-x+iy)}-\frac2i\sum_{n=1,3,5,...}e^{n(-x-iy)}
\\
&=\frac1i\Ln\frac{1+e^{-x+iy}}{1-e^{-x+iy}}-\frac1i\Ln\frac{1+e^{-x-iy}}{1-e^{-x-iy}}
\\
&=\frac1i\Ln\frac{1-e^{-x-iy}+e^{-x+iy}-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-x-iy}-e^{-x+iy}-e^{-2x}}
\\
&=\frac1i\Ln\frac{\sinh x+i\sin y}{\sinh x-i\sin y}\\
&=2\arg(\sinh x+i\sin y)=2\tan^{-1}\frac{\sin y}{\sinh x}
\end{align}

Comment: Could you define the Ln function please?

Comment: It is the notation for the main branch of the logarithm over the complex plane, ${\rm Ln}(z)=\ln|z|+i\arg(z)$. All expressions inside the logarithm have positive real part, so no crossing of the negative real axis occurs.